# Concurrency Leetcode problem raise a Time Limit Exceeded without any understandable reason

Tags: python, multithreading

Learning concurrency and threading lock, i tried this problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/building-h2o (explanation of the problem in the link).

My code aim to release  in order: Hydrogen 2 times before releasing Oxygen. So with the test case "HOH" (which means in Leetcode: Thread "hydrogen" arrive in first, then a thread "oxygen" and finally an other thread "hydrogen" arrive). My code should let the first thread running, then block the "oxygen" thread till the last thread "hydrogen" is ran and lastly release the previous thread "oxygen" running.

I got a time Limit Exceeded on the test case "HOH" , so i feel there is perhaps a deadlock in my solution but not sure. Have you any idea ?

```
import threading

class H2O:
    def __init__(self):
        print("init")
        self.lock1 = threading.Lock()
        self.lock2 = threading.Lock()
        self.H = 0
        self.lock1.acquire()
        self.lock2.acquire()

    def hydrogen(self, releaseHydrogen: 'Callable[[], None]') -> None:
        if self.H<2:
            # releaseHydrogen() outputs "H". Do not change or remove this line.
            print("release H")
            releaseHydrogen()
            self.H+=1
        else:
            self.lock2.release()
            self.lock1.acquire()
            
        

    def oxygen(self, releaseOxygen: 'Callable[[], None]') -> None:
        self.lock2.acquire()
        # releaseOxygen() outputs "O". Do not change or remove this line.
        print("release O")
        releaseOxygen()
        self.H=0
        self.lock1.release()
```

EDIT:
I wrote here a minimal example (cooked by me), but i suppose it is better to run the code on the Leetcode platform (test case and interactive function are way better implemented by them):

```
from threading import Thread
import threading
import time

def releaseOxygen():
    print("O")

def releaseHydrogen():
    print("H")


class H2O:
    def __init__(self):
        print("init")
        self.lock1 = threading.Lock()
        self.lock2 = threading.Lock()
        self.H = 0
        self.lock1.acquire()
        self.lock2.acquire()

    def hydrogen(self, releaseHydrogen: 'Callable[[], None]') -> None:
        if self.H<2:
            # releaseHydrogen() outputs "H". Do not change or remove this line.
            print("release H")
            releaseHydrogen()
            self.H+=1
        else:
            self.lock2.release()
            self.lock1.acquire()
            
        

    def oxygen(self, releaseOxygen: 'Callable[[], None]') -> None:
        self.lock2.acquire()
        # releaseOxygen() outputs "O". Do not change or remove this line.
        print("release O")
        releaseOxygen()
        self.H=0
        self.lock1.release()




if __name__ == "__main__":
    H2o = H2O()
    thread = threading.Thread(target = H2o.hydrogen,args=(releaseHydrogen,))
    thread2 = threading.Thread(target = H2o.oxygen,args=(releaseOxygen,))
    thread3 = threading.Thread(target = H2o.hydrogen,args=(releaseHydrogen,))
    print("thread 1")
    thread.start()
    time.sleep(0.2)
    print("thread 2")
    thread2.start()
    time.sleep(0.2)
    print("thread 3")
    thread3.start()
    thread.join()
    thread2.join()
    thread3.join()
    print('Finished')
```

Comment: You'll have to show how this class is used, aka a [mre]

Comment: It is based on the leetcode platform, so i can't reproduce the internals in leetcode. I supposed it is based on complicated concurrency module to launch the different thread, i can try to write such a code but it ll probably be different that internal leetcode representation. Hope i am clear with the explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the initializer is called from a different thread than the calls to `hydrogen` and `oxygen`. As a result, the locks that are required in the initializer are never released again and all subsequent acquisitions will block.

One possible solution takes advantages of `threading.Condition`.

```py
class H2O:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cond = threading.Condition()
        self.H = 0
        self.O = 0
        
    def hydrogen(self, releaseHydrogen: 'Callable[[], None]') -> None:
        with self.cond:
            while self.H == 2:
                self.cond.wait()
            self.H += 1
            releaseHydrogen()
            self.check_H2O()

    def oxygen(self, releaseOxygen: 'Callable[[], None]') -> None:
        with self.cond:
            while self.O == 1:
                self.cond.wait()
            self.O += 1
            releaseOxygen()
            self.check_H2O()
                    
    def check_H2O(self) -> None:
        if self.H == 2 and self.O == 1:
            # Reset
            self.H = 0
            self.O = 0
            # Notify other threads
            self.cond.notify_all()
```